# ELB Different route for outbound connections from webserver

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc, vpc

I'm currently in the process of moving all our servers/services to AWS, but we have an issue where our webserver connects to a webservice on our client's server to retrieve information when users login. Most of our customers restrict their webservice by our IP at firewall NAT level as well as a password built into the webservice.

When using ELB  our IP will change. Is there no way of specifying a default gateway for the ELB servers therefore traffic can come in and respond on whichever IP the ELB chooses, however by default anything like web browsing or .NET connecting to a webservice on the web server would connect via a static IP gateway?

This works on our current setup as we have NAT rules for web and default gateway setup too, therefore each thing is separate.

Regards

Liam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ELB will not be making outbound connections to your client's server; your web server will make that connection. The data flow looks like:

```
Internet => ELB => Web server(s)
```

Then your web server submits any upstream requests

```
Web server(s) => Client server(s)
```

In this case, you need to supply your client with the elastic IP address (EIP) you've assigned to your web servers. So long as you do not release the EIP it will not change.

If you're in a VPC, and your web servers are in private subnets, the outbound connection is like this

```
Web server(s) => VPC NAT server => Client server(s)
```

In this scenario, your outbound connections will be routed through the NAT server. You need to give your client the public IP address of the NAT server, which also will not change so long as you do not release the EIP.

Comment: Hi Ben,Thanks for the reply, I'll test this out when they're live. I thought this would be the case, but was advised it wasn't by another company which our directors have brought in to advise and setup the infrastructure. I'll report back to confirm in the next couple of days :-) Regards Liam

Comment: The ELB will only accept requests from clients and distribute those requests among your web servers. Your web servers initiate all upstream connections; the ELBs IP will not be seen by the upstream servers at all.

Comment: Hi Ben, just to confirm that eveything you said was spot on. Glad i confirmed this one as they were saying I'd have to configure a proxy to be used in all my code!.. Liam